# validation rule date field

Tags: validation, validation-rule, date

I am doing first time in validation rule. I need this scenario Date field must be today or up to 367 days in the future. Could you please suggest the formula for the same.

I did this way but it is working only today and greater than 367 days but i need only up to 367 days in future

```
AND(OR(ISNEW(),ISCHANGED(Date__c)),Date__c< TODAY())
```

Answer (score 2):

You're simply missing the part that sets a maximum value. You need to use an `OR` for the ranges as well, since it can be either before or after the range of today to 367 days from now, but never both.

```
AND(
    OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Date__c))
    OR(Date__c < TODAY(), Date__c > TODAY() + 367)
)
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thank you for your help...Now working fine

Comment: @Mahitha Glad to hear it! If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.